# How do we decide if a biblical instruction is cultural or transcultural?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, cultural-analysis

We ignore many instructions in the Bible, but keep some. For instance women do not stay silent in church or wear head coverings during prayer.

How do we decide if a verse was written for the culture of the day, or if it is timeless?

Comment: Head covering wasn't hats.  It is what you see middle-eastern women wear, and it was anywhere in public.

Comment: Different denominations would disagree about what instructions are cultural or transculural.  For example, women do wear head coverings in some denominations.  Probably a better way to ask this question would be to ask about a specific instruction and why some think or do not think that it is a cultural command.

Comment: I have voted to re-open this question. The close reason given was about theological questions not being attached to a text being off topic, but this question isn't looking for the answer to a theological issue it's about the process of hermeneutics itself. That makes it squarely **on topic**. Now this question might be a bit too broad, and if people want to vote to close it based on _that reason_ I'll cede they might have a point.

Comment: Augustine, and no doubt others, felt that an interpretation was good if it helped one follow the two greatest commandments. We might turn that into a criterion for laws: Does a given law, transposed to my time and place, help me to love God and my neighbour? If so it applies.

Comment: "For instance women do not stay silent in church or wear head coverings during prayer." Traditionally for Catholics and in Orthodoxy, actually this is the *modus operandi*.

Answer (score 2):

To answer a question whether a specific instruction given in Scripture is cultural or transcultural you would have to dive into the culture of that time.

If you read more about the culture of that time, or specifically surrounding a particular church where the apostle Paul wrote to, there may be a little bit of an answer. For example when it comes to the instruction for women to cover the head, it was a local and temporary custom that had prostitutes and the like shave their head. The city of Corinth was rampant with prostitutes. So in order to prevent other people judging them because of it, or to give the impression they were bringing dishonor to the husband, they were instructed to wear hair coverings. Also head shaving was associated with the punishment for adultery.

So the covering of the head literally is an instruction for that church.
And transculturally it would have an implication for us today that women are not to dishonor their husbands, for example a married woman not wearing her wedding ring or act as if she is available.

Source: Mark Finney, “[Honour, Head-coverings and Headship: 1 Corinthians 11.2-16 in its Social Context](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.299952!/file/JSNT.pdf),” *Journal for the Study of the New Testament* 33.1 (2010): 31-58.

Answer (score 0):

The more information we have the better.  For example:  What did it mean for a woman in the 1st century to be in public without her head covered? What would be the equivalent in this year in the U.S.?  What would be the equivalent in this year in central Africa?

Example:  A woman could cover her head in central Africa but not represent the intent of the verse by being in public with her knees uncovered.

With some of the passages like a woman speaking in church we may not have a historical reason for this.  It's just what God has intended without explanation.  In cases like this we can understand from other passages that it doesn't mean women cannot teach other women in church, woman will lose their salvation if they speak, or that women do not have a part in the great commission, evangelism, or in serving in the church.

Answer (score 0):

For all of the commands in scripture I ask two questions.

1. What is the intention of the command?
2. What is the situation when the command was given?

The intention of the command should be transcultural, but the situation of the command may change. If the situation changes, the way the intention is applied may also change. An example from modernity, we have speed limits. The intention is to limit speeds to keep people safe. However, if we were to have self-driving cars, the application of that intention may change. We may no longer limit cars by speed, but by some other computational metric. Either way the intention remains as transcultural, the application is culturally specific.

As one might realize, different denominations will identify different intentions and situations, and thus come to different conclusions for the present time. An example of this for the headcoverings, is whether the cultural situation is worship, morning or marriage. Each of which can be justified by history. Thus, my recommendation is to be patient in interpretation and read multiple sides and interpretations.

**Cult Practice**

> but the priestess of the god must enter his sanctuary, with a white veil drawn over her head and face.
>   Pausanias, *Descriptions of Greece* 6.20

**Mourning Rituals**

> Or is it that the unusual is proper in mourning, and it is more usual for women to go forth in public with their heads covered and men with their heads uncovered? So in Greece, whenever any misfortune comes, the women cut off their hair and the men let it grow, for it is usual for men to have their hair cut and for women to let it grow.
>   Plutarch *Moralia* 267

**Marriage**

> When someone inquired why they took their girls into public places unveiled, but their married women veiled, he said, "Because the girls have to find husbands, and the married women have to keep to those who have them!"
>   Plutarch *Moralia* 232